# Convert array of 2-tuples into one nested two elements array

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

I am looking for the functional programming term (if it exists) of a function which converts an array of several 2-tuples into one 2-tuple array.

I think the best way to illustrate my question is through an example. I want to convert `array` to `newArray`:

```js
const array = [[10, "A"], [20, "B"], [30, "C"], [40, "D"]]
const newArray = [[10, 20, 30, 40], ["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
```

My favorite language is javascript and I know I could do this through hacking with `reduce` but I would like to know if I can find a function like this in functional programming libraries like for example *Ramda*.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally called `unzip` (with `zip` being the operation going in the other direction).

Answer (score 0):

In ramda [transpose](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#transpose) works both ways.
You basically want to:

> turn a list of `n` lists of length `x`, into a list of `x` lists of length `n`.

```js
const initial = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']];

const result = R.transpose(initial);
console.log('result is', result);

const data = R.transpose(result);
console.log('data is', data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha256-xB25ljGZ7K2VXnq087unEnoVhvTosWWtqXB4tAtZmHU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

Also look at:

1. [zip](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip)